# Wp_mail doesnt work

Tags: php, email, wp-mail

I created a form for mail sending, but it does not work. Email function is enabled in php.

```
if (!$error_msg) {
    $to = "mail@to.send";
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
    $headers[] = 'From: ' . $fullname . ' <' . $mail . '>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail($to, $object, $message, $headers);
    $error_msg_type = 'success';
    $error_msg = __('cont_mail_sent', 'Theme');
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `wp_mail ( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments )` [Always read docs before asking](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/). You can also find examples if you scroll down.

Comment: $attachments is not optional?

Comment: `$attachements` is optional. does `$object` represent `$subject`? Are you declaring it? It's required. Also add more code, if all required fields are there, you have a bug somewhere else.

Comment: Yes all is declared, only $headers is an array

Answer (score 0):

f you're using anything that allows you to configure SMTP within WordPress, take it out.

Then put everything into a function:

```
add_action('init','delay_until_init');
function delay_until_init(){
   // call wp_mail() here
}
```